# Filter Configuration/Adb commands for viewing only Verbose (AND) Debug Logs in Android Studio

Tags: android, adb, logcat, android-logcat, android-studio-2.2

How can I create a filter in Android Studio to view only V/ and D/ (Verbose and Debug) Logs only. Currently I can select only one at a time.

Alternatively, is there an `adb` command to capture Debug and Verbose level logs messages only?

**UPDATE :**

I am developing a power manager Android Application and want to trace down from lower layer (Androdi Framework) to Application level logs .My application shows V/(verbose) logs while there is D/BatteryService Logs , I just want V/ and D/ logs  .SO I was wondering if I can gather only these two types -(V/ and D/) and Subtypes (MyAPP and BatteryService) of logs using Android Studio. If not from Android Studio, then the coresponding adb command for console.

Answer (score 0):

The priority based filters in `logcat` (as in many other logging systems) do not 
mean to limit the filtered messages to a single priority level. Instead they set the *lowest* level to show.

`adb logcat -s *:D` is not going to show `debug` messages only - it will show `debug` , `info`, `warning`, `error` and `fatal` messages. But not `verbose` because it is lower level than `debug`

I do not see the use case for what you are asking. But you could just `grep` for whatever combination of priority levels you want:

```
adb logcat -v tag | grep -E '^(V|D)/'
```

Comment: Update the Use case in the Question.

Comment: @Raulp, your use case does not explain why you want to filter by priorities. In your case you should just filter by 2 tags and ignore the priorities: `adb logcat -s MyAPP:* BatteryService:*`